# Add a new list in a new line on a .txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to add a list to an existing .txt file in Python three. Currently I have the following code:

```
def function(list, new_add):
    with open("file.txt", new_add) as file:
        for item in list:
            file.write("{}\t".format(item))


add_grade(list, "w")
```

I have created a list:

```
list = [string1, integer1a, integer1b]
```

It works fine creating a new txt file. But if I replace "w" with "a" I do not get the purposed output. My question is now, how do I add new components of a list to the file in a new line? My current output look like this if I try to add new variables:

string1  integer1a  integer1b   string2  integer2a  integer2a

I would like instead **the following displayed**:

string1  integer1a  integer1b

string2  integer2a  integer2a

...

How could I add a new line after the each list is inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with the Python 3 [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) function, just specify the separator and file with the `sep` and `file` parameters, and `print()` will take care of the details for you:

```
def function(iterable, filename, new_add):
    with open(filename, new_add) as file:
        print(*iterable, sep='\t', file=file)
```

Note that I renamed the `list` parameter to `iterable` because using `list` shadows the built-in `list` class, and the function should work with any iterable.

This code will also work in Python 2 if you add the following to the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Good point about the `list` overload. Just suggested a similar edit in the other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

this should work , you should call line break after writing your list in the file

```
def add_grade(list, new_add):
    with open("file.txt", new_add) as file:
        for item in list:
            file.write("{}\t".format(item))
        file.write("\n")


add_grade(list, "w")
```